# When a page fault is returned from disk to physical memory, where is the page placed?

Tags: architecture, operating-system, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, page-fault

I'm confused about this. Don't all physical memory address directly correspond to their physical memory locations? For example, physical address 0x1000 is in the 0x1000's spot of physical memory, etc.

In that case, when you have a page fault by accessing a page not in memory, you would be accessing something out of bounds, so where in physical memory would that page go when it is returned from disk?

I might be misunderstanding virtual memory.

Comment: Page faults happen in virtual memory, not physical memory.

Comment: It goes in the physical page (aka page frame) the OS allocates, and then maps the faulting virtual page to that new physical page.  (The OS passes the right physical address to the disk controller for it to DMA the sectors into physical memory.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bit of confusion. Processes only see LOGICAL ADDRESSES. Logical addresses are mapped to PHYSICAL ADDRESSES using PAGE TABLES.

A page fault occurs when a process accesses a logical address that does not have a mapping to a physical address.

When a page fault occurs, the operating system needs to find a free page in physical memory. That field can be anywhere in memory. The operating system then needs map the free physical page frame to the logical page that caused the page fault by updating the process page tables. Then it needs to copy the page data from VIRTUAL secondary storage to the free physical memory page that is now part of the process address space.

Comment: It needs to page in the correct contents from disk *before* updating the page table for the faulting process.  Otherwise another thread in the same process could access the page before it was filled, even if the faulting thread stays blocked.  Or if it's single-threaded, then there's no ordering requirement as long as you don't wake up the process until both are done.

Comment: That depends on the system. The page needs to be mapped in some way by some page table before the data can be copied.

Comment: First, no it doesn't, DMA works on physical address.  And 2nd, usually the OS has its own kernel mapping of physical memory separate from the virtual address space of user-space processes, so it could use this for non-DMA I/O through the CPU.  (e.g. "high half" kernels use the high half of virtual address space for kernel addresses, often including a big contiguous mapping of all of physical memory.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Higher_Half_Kernel)

Comment: Not on all processors.

Comment: Which part of my comment are you saying isn't true on all processors?  I guess virtual DMA is plausible, and I could maybe imagine an OS that doesn't map memory other than with the same mappings that user-space uses.  But only if *both* those things were true would you not be able to start DMA before starting to modify the page tables.

Comment: There are processors that cannot do disk I/O to memory unless that memory is mapped (and remains mapped) to a process address space. On the PDP-11 you could do I/O without such a mapping. On the VAX you could not.

Comment: Presumably you want to do I/O to a kernel mapping of that page, so it can happen in the background (in an interrupt handler) while a *different* user-space task is running with a different mapping for that virtual address.  You don't want to have the entire system or CPU core (mostly) idle from page-fault to completion of disk I/O.

Comment: Yes, you'd do a mapping to the system space then remap to the user space once the data is loaded. That seem too complicated for the user's question.

Comment: My point is that many kernels *already* have a contiguous 1:1 mapping of the entire physical address space into a big range of their virtual address space, unless running on cramped hardware like 32-bit x86 with more than 1 or 2GB of RAM.  Or even worse, with PAE so physical address space can be even *larger* than virtual.  And DMA to highmem might be problematic on such systems, making it even worse.  Anyway, if you want to explain it simply, just say that disk controllers can DMA to a physical address, and/or elide any discussion of anything but user-space using the mapping.